# Waiting for asynchronously-executed block to finish

Tags: ios, asynchronous, objective-c-blocks

I have a simple problem... I hope the solution is simple, too!

Here is my code:

```
__block NSString * response; //the result !

[deviceInfo.geocoder reverseGeocodeLocation:deviceInfo.locationProperties completionHandler:

 ^(NSArray *placemarks, NSError *error) {

     [placemarks copy];
     //Get nearby address
     CLPlacemark *placemark = [placemarks objectAtIndex:0];

     NSLog(@"Country : %@",placemark.country);
     response =placemark.country;
 }
 ];

//-----------------------------------------------
NSLog(@"Response COUNTRY : %@",response); // response = NULL /!\
```

Inside the block, `placemark.country` equals to `UK`.

How can I have `response = placemark.country` outside the block?

Comment: That block is obviously run asynchronously, and so `response` won't get populated until the block is actually called, which will *very likely* be way after the 2nd `NSLog()` statement is executed.  You need to learn something about (a)synchronous execution of code.

Comment: Then, how can I wait for the end of the asynchronous method ?

Comment: Do something else while you wait and get the block to call one of your methods with the result, which can then update the UI, or do whatever is next on the list of things to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the point where your NSLog line is run, your completion block has not yet been called. reverseGeocodeLocation is a non-blocking call, which is why it takes a completion handler.

What you DON'T want to do is to turn this into a synchronous method. I presume you want to update your UI in response to the geocode completing. Do something like this:

I don't see what the "[placemarks copy]" line is supposed to achieve. It's completely pointless because you're ignoring the return value.

```
[deviceInfo.geocoder reverseGeocodeLocation:deviceInfo.locationProperties completionHandler:

 ^(NSArray *placemarks, NSError *error) {

     [placemarks copy];
     //Get nearby address
     CLPlacemark *placemark = [placemarks objectAtIndex:0];

     NSLog(@"Country : %@",placemark.country);
     // No need for response to be a __block variable.
     NSString *response =placemark.country;
     dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
       [self updateUIWithResponse:response];
    }
 ];

 -(void)updateUIWithResponse:(NSString*)response
 {
     NSLog(@"Got a response: %@), response);
 }
```

Comment: Thank you !
the [placemarks copy]; was just an error when I copied/pasted my text